# Git workflow for Email projects

Tags: git, email, zurb-foundation

Does anybody know of the best Git workflows for working with templates in a project?

Essentially, I'd like to have a Git repo of HTML email templates. The email developer would grab a copy of the template they want (or fork it), create the email and then commit it back to the same repo (but obviously not overriding the template that it came from).

Is this a simple case of using branching/forking..? Or is there a specific workflow that would work best for this?

Comment: We've used inky templates as source files and ignored the generated and inlined files. Basically create a new email project with the Foundation CLI.